# Encrypted Traffic on Private Network

Tags: ssl, encryption, raspberry-pi, electron, localhost

I'd appreciate some help with thinking through a problem. On a local network, I have:

- A raspberry pi with some server software on it
- A separate computer running an electron app, which is supposed to talk to the RPi through websockets. The user enters the IP address of the RPi into the app, and a connection is opened.

I need a good way to secure communication between this electron app and the RPi. I've looked into using SSL/TLS with secure websockets, but it doesn't *seem* like this is a good idea (feel free to tell me otherwise)

Has anyone implemented something like this or encountered a similar problem? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think your question is ontopic here as it stands, but about "I've looked into using SSL/TLS with secure websockets, but it doesn't seem like this is a good idea", you may want to expand on how you arrived at the conclusion that it is not a good idea so that people understand your train of thought.

Comment: TLS is indeed the standard way to solve this sort of problem.  Can you elaborate on why you think that TLS is not a good fit for your application?

Comment: This question belongs to another site, but I'm not even going to indicate that it needs migration as you don't seem to respond to the comments.